# Turn off iPad on-screen keyboard using Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Desktop Keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, microsoft

I'm using Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Desktop Keyboard with an iPad. This works great, except I'm not able to turn off the onscreen keyboard.  I understand that there is an eject button on the Apple Bluetooth keyboard that allows turning on and off the onscreen keyboard.  Is there a key combination that I can use to do the same on the Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Desktop Keyboard?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm trying to connect Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Desktop set to iPad 6, but only the mouse works. The keyboard is paired, but I can't type anything in any application. The on-screen keyboard is not hiding too.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft doesn't officially support iOS with the Designer Keyboard. They actually list it on their website as non-functional with iOS. This strikes me as a very inconvenient step seeing as I am using it right now on the iPad Pro and it is hands down better than any other iPad keyboard I have used... other that that idiotic refusal to dismiss the virtual keyboard when in use!

Comment: Did you do something else besides entering the pin code to get it working? Mine does not appeear to be working with iPad 6.